# Request of a file appears in the response of a request

Tags: wireshark, ms-yarp

I have a ms yarp and a backend server which is only accessible through the yarp. I noticed that some web pages are not displayed properly, because for example png or css files are not loaded correctly.
I ran Wireshark on the backend server. For a css that is not loading properly, I see the following in the TCP stream. /JunkData is supposed to be loaded. The get request for the css that is not loading appears in the response.
Has anyone seen something like this before? Can anyone give me a tip on what to do about this?

```
GET /JunkData?Init=1&xts=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1:1111
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, */*; q=0.8, application/signed-exchange; v=b3; q=0.7
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5735.199 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE, de; q=0.9, en-US; q=0.8, en; q=0.7
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-length: 34634
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Encoding: gzip
Expires: Tue, 29 Feb 2000 01:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: D=12341234; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict


Some encoded/encyprted data like this:
.>%....-]........]I....O..B.\.]E:../%Ez%..........O.H...2....w...?..O..8...n.?|.._....s....gY..G.n.D.u. ..J7...:......=....bJF{..b...Y..&.....\a..?..ya..j.0M..Gz..M C.=_..$..#.].<....=......z......V%7....],.(..$..,
z..O..q....H..k.gx....Q..qf.......j.v.....t..z^x.......o.... ...<..!..h......*..b..,...._..
)..*....e:..d..N/..dD....G%N.<
. .T....;&........c.......K.A.{........q".l'..b.O..?6...../.>..Idu}....}....B...o..;...c..I..v..o3...w.......$...tn...g<b.(S..v .+c\...Ty-Yy.zA2.r.\.....dC......).D....G..P.:.U.5...l.[.lG6.....{..A}cEzD.....}}.........Hv..Z.........>.....:oz8..N?.T.L{._q..F+@.i.T!.q.....R2.......*Y\...~.....l....uE5W...d...-.0..........I2/.O.R?.9..l{.v.[.n@.H.....Av...tEO..X.KS....xA...3.k6...6..FxZ.b.8.Vn....].H}.....'.+. ....p../M...z......."S.r......i}..F.=o..%..o.........5<-.l..]...q^..xU....U|..c..r<....\.?..e..'.x.....ux....{.o..9O...^h....w-<..L.{.&#.lxN.|......8.......q....u^J.h&.......(F...)F...*...r.e...\"......$..z.#.........4E.....E......^u.f.A..L...7.......p.U..=x........4........c.i.........1.ybQ..3.w.8...?.8..4.D...@!...Rp0.g...K.8.Rq.........s.}..@....M..6..#..7HE:ad....j...(......f.y..F..../o/O.._...L:.."
..GET /css/foo.css HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1:1111
Accept: text/css, */*; q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.5735.199 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: de-DE, de; q=0.9, en-US; q=0.8, en; q=0.7
Referer: https://myproxy:7285/JunkData?Init=1&xts=1
```